# Enzyme - TS2350: Only a void function can be called with the 'new' keyword

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme

After configuring the following:

```
import * as enzyme from 'enzyme';
import * as Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

When running `jest --watch`, everything works as expected. But, when running `webpack --watch`, I get: 
`TS2350: Only a void function can be called with the 'new' keyword.`

I couldn't find a solution, and I don't understand what's wrong.

I would love to get a hand. 
Thanks.

Comment: try `import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';` instead

Answer (score 10):

I missed `yarn add @types/enzyme-adapter-react-16`

That fixed it.